# An example of a unit ball $B(0,1)$ which is not convex

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, convex-analysis

Example 9.9 of Bruckner's real analysis defines the following metric :

Let $\mathcal{S}$ denote the measurable, finite a.e. functions on $[0,1]$, and let $ρ(f, g)= \int_0^1 \dfrac{|f−g|}{1+|f−g|} dλ$.

In Chapter 12, it is claimed without a proof that the unit ball $B(0,1)$ is not convex.

So, $\int_0^1 \dfrac{|f|}{1+|f|} dλ <1$ and $\int_0^1 \dfrac{|g|}{1+|g|} dλ <1$. How $\int_0^1 \dfrac{|\alpha f + (1- \alpha)g|}{1+|\alpha f + (1- \alpha)g|} dλ \le \int_0^1 \dfrac{\alpha |f|}{1+|\alpha f + (1- \alpha)g|} + \dfrac{(1- \alpha)|g|}{1+|\alpha f + (1- \alpha)g|} dλ <1$ ?

For example if we had $\int_0^1 \dfrac{|f|}{1+|\alpha f + (1- \alpha)g|} \le \int_0^1 \dfrac{|f|}{1+|f|}$ for any $0<\alpha<1$ that would've been great!

Comment: Hint: define a similiar metric in $\mathbb R^2:$  $$d(x,y)=\frac{|x_1-y_1|}{1+|x_1-x_2|}+\frac{|x_2-y_2|}{1+|x_2-y_2|}$$ then show that a ball under this metric is not convex in $\mathbb R^2,$ , and use that to find a subspace in your space by picking a subspace of your space that is equivalent to $\mathbb R^2.$

Comment: Another hint: $\frac{x}{x+1}=1-\frac1{x+1}.$ In particular, if $x,y\geq 0$ then $\frac{x}{x+1}+\frac y{y+1}<1$ iff $$1<\frac{1}{1+{x}}+\frac1{1+y}$$ or $$(1+x)(1+y) <2+(x+y)$$ or $$xy<1.$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, I couldn't get any idea from your hints so I edited my post.

Comment: Actually, this isn’t true. Just note that if $u\geq 0$ then $0\leq \frac{u}{u+1}<1$ so the definition $d(f,g)<1$ for for all $f,g.$ In particular, any unit ball is the whole space, which is convex. But other balls of radius $<1$ are not convex.

Comment: For $p \in [1,\infty]$ and $n \in \mathbb N_*$, let $B_{n,p}$ be the unit-ball in $\mathbb R^n$ equipped with the $\ell_p$ metric. Then $B_{n,p}$ is convex iff $p \ge 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true, because a unit ball contains the entire space.

This is because if $h$ is such a function, then $$h_0(x)=\frac{|hx)|}{1+|h(x)|}<1$$ for all $x,$ so:

$$F(h)=\int_0^1 h_0(x)<1.$$ In particular, $B(0,1)$ is the whole space, so it is convex.

But then $d(f,g) =F(f-g)<1$

However: the ball $B(0,1/2)$ is not convex.

Let $$\begin{align}g_1(x)&=\begin{cases}2&x<\frac12\\
\frac{1}{3}&x\geq \frac12.\end{cases}\\
g_2(x)&=\begin{cases}1/3&x<\frac12\\2&x\geq \frac12.\end{cases}\end{align}$$
Show $g_1,g_2$ are in the ball of radius $\frac12$ around the zero function. Then show,that $\frac12(g_1+g_2)$ is not in that ball.